# Difference between data of two different row belonging to two different columns in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Sample Table:

```
Waiter      Customer_In_Time    Customer_Out_Time   Date
Pallavi            10:00                12:00        7/5/2020 
Pallavi            13:15                13:50        7/5/2020
Pallavi            15:10                16:35        7/5/2020
Pallavi            10:30                12:00        8/5/2020
Ayush              9:30                 10:45        7/5/2020
Ayush              10:30                12:00        8/5/2020
Ayush              13:45                15:00        8/5/2020
```

I need a column which calculates the time difference of Free time of a day. Example for Pallavi on 7/5/2020 between first customer out time and second customer in time that is 75 mins and if there is only a single customer for a day then the output for that waiter for that day is 0.

Comment: (Links to) Images of data don't help us help you. Take the time to post data in a **consumable** format; either tabular formatted `text` or as DDL and DML statements. As for your "question", what is your question? You don't ask anything here, just tell us what you "need". Stack Overflow isn't a free coding service, please don't treat it like one. Take the time to show your attempts, explain why they don't work and/or tell us what research you performed to help *you* solve the problem and what about it you didn't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `lag()` to get the previous out time and then aggregate:

```
select waiter, date,
       coalesce(sum(datediff(minute, prev_cot, customer_in_time)), 0) as free_minutes
from (select t.*,
             lag(customer_out_time) over (partition by waiter, date order by customer_in_time) as prev_cot
      from t
     ) t
group by waiter, date;
```

In older, unsupported versions of SQL Server, you can use `apply`:

```
select waiter, date,
       coalesce(sum(datediff(minute, prev_cot, customer_in_time)), 0) as free_minutes
from (select t.*,
             tprev.customer_out_time as prev_cot
      from t outer apply
           (select top (1) t2.*
            from t t2
            where t2.waiter = t.waiter and t2.date = t.date and
                  t2.customer_in_time < t.customer_in_time
            order by t2.customer_in_time desc
           ) tprev
     ) t
group by waiter, date;
```

Comment: thankyou for the query ... but the error is coming as
'lag' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: @Rudra are you using an unsupported version of SQL Server? `LAG` is available in every supported version of SQL Server, including those only in extended support. If so, you should really be telling the the users here that when you post your question. I also suggest looking at upgrade paths asap,

Comment: The SQL Server Version I am having is 2008 and lag is applicable for 2012 is there an alternative for this solution

Comment: You'll have to use a Self Join, @Rudra. But, like I said, you should *really* be upgrading your version; 2008 has been completely unsupported for a year now.

Comment: Thankyou @Larnu Please help me with the solution with self join.. I am a beginner and I have to submit this .. little urgent.. I tried alot but keep getting errors

Comment: *"I have to submit this"* That implies this is homework. If it's homework, you should be doing it, not us.

Comment: Hi .. I never said it's an homework.. It's a really big query on a big database.. What I asked was just a part of it.. cozz I was stuck.. Sorry if this doubt offended you.. Thankyou for your time